# Visual Studio 2015 - using @home and @work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, account

I have in mind to purchase new visual studio 2015 professional.
But i have doubt (and google didn't find for me answer) can i use it at home and work, same version with same MSDN account.

I'm not gonna use it at the same time obviously.

Comment: You don't have to buy it at all - Visual Studio 2015 Community is free and equivalent to Pro. Even small professional teams are allowed to use it. It's free for hobbyists, open source and individual programmers. What you buy with Pro is the MSDN subscription and the tons of software it provides

Comment: Yes, i know. sounds good to me. Maybe i will go with Enterprise version (more money) but have Coded UI testing, what i'm using mostly. I mean that's the main reason for purchasing VS2015.

Comment: What is the question then? Besides, licensing questions are best answered by reading the license terms of each subscription package. MSDN subscriptions are per *person*, not per PC or company anyway

Comment: Question is as i written. Can i use it at home and work, same version with same MSDN account.

Comment: Either way this question is way off topic for SO.

Comment: VS always had a very flexible license, you can use it on any machine as long as the copies are not used at the same time.  Just check that your employer doesn't object, some do.

Comment: Based on your location (Sarajevo), just send a mail or call to [Microsoft sales for your country](http://www.microsoft.com/bih/cpe/contacts.aspx). If you ask at the sales department, they are usually happy to respond, because usually it leads to new income for them. [Or here](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msmea/hr_BA/DisplayHelpContactUsPage/ThemeID.27659900/Currency.USD/mktp.BA). Just browse the web.

Comment: Miroxlav, already did ,thanks